# Error when calling dotnet restore in Dockerfile

Tags: .net, docker, visual-studio-code, .net-6.0

I'm trying to build a Docker image using **docker build** command for my .Net 6.0 project.
The project runs normally and there are no issues but when I tried to run the docker command I will hit **Failed to restore /src/src/KMS.HttpApi.Host/KMS.HttpApi.Host.csproj**.

**Docker Command**
`docker build -t kmsapi .`

**Error**

```
#98 77.99   Failed to restore /src/src/KMS.HttpApi.Host/KMS.HttpApi.Host.csproj (in 41.3 sec).
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c dotnet restore "src/KMS.HttpApi.Host/KMS.HttpApi.Host.csproj"]: exit code: 1
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["NuGet.Config", "."]
COPY ["modules/ISaraanRegistration/NuGet.Config", "modules/ISaraanRegistration/"]
COPY ["modules/Registration/NuGet.Config", "modules/Registration/"]
COPY ["modules/IAkaunActivation/NuGet.Config", "modules/IAkaunActivation/"]
COPY ["modules/TAC/NuGet.Config", "modules/TAC/"]
COPY ["modules/Helper/NuGet.Config", "modules/Helper/"]
COPY ["modules/ThumbprintVerification/NuGet.Config", "modules/ThumbprintVerification/"]
COPY ["modules/IShariahRegistration/NuGet.Config", "modules/IShariahRegistration/"]
COPY ["modules/MemberProfile/NuGet.Config", "modules/MemberProfile/"]
COPY ["modules/MemberAccount/NuGet.Config", "modules/MemberAccount/"]
COPY ["modules/MemberDetailInquiry/NuGet.Config", "modules/MemberDetailInquiry/"]
COPY ["modules/IAkaunRegistration/NuGet.Config", "modules/IAkaunRegistration/"]
COPY ["src/KMS.HttpApi.Host/KMS.HttpApi.Host.csproj", "src/KMS.HttpApi.Host/"]
COPY ["src/KMS.EntityFrameworkCore/KMS.EntityFrameworkCore.csproj", "src/KMS.EntityFrameworkCore/"]
COPY ["modules/ISaraanRegistration/src/ISaraanRegistration.EntityFrameworkCore/ISaraanRegistration.EntityFrameworkCore.csproj", "modules/ISaraanRegistration/src/ISaraanRegistration.EntityFrameworkCore/"]
COPY ["modules/ISaraanRegistration/src/ISaraanRegistration.Domain/ISaraanRegistration.Domain.csproj", "modules/ISaraanRegistration/src/ISaraanRegistration.Domain/"]
COPY ["modules/ISaraanRegistration/src/ISaraanRegistration.Domain.Shared/ISaraanRegistration.Domain.Shared.csproj", "modules/ISaraanRegistration/src/ISaraanRegistration.Domain.Shared/"]
COPY ["modules/Registration/src/Registration.EntityFrameworkCore/Registration.EntityFrameworkCore.csproj", "modules/Registration/src/Registration.EntityFrameworkCore/"]
COPY ["modules/Registration/src/Registration.Domain/Registration.Domain.csproj", "modules/Registration/src/Registration.Domain/"]
COPY ["modules/Registration/src/Registration.Domain.Shared/Registration.Domain.Shared.csproj", "modules/Registration/src/Registration.Domain.Shared/"]
COPY ["modules/IAkaunActivation/src/IAkaunActivation.EntityFrameworkCore/IAkaunActivation.EntityFrameworkCore.csproj", "modules/IAkaunActivation/src/IAkaunActivation.EntityFrameworkCore/"]
COPY ["modules/IAkaunActivation/src/IAkaunActivation.Domain/IAkaunActivation.Domain.csproj", "modules/IAkaunActivation/src/IAkaunActivation.Domain/"]
COPY ["modules/IAkaunActivation/src/IAkaunActivation.Domain.Shared/IAkaunActivation.Domain.Shared.csproj", "modules/IAkaunActivation/src/IAkaunActivation.Domain.Shared/"]
COPY ["modules/TAC/src/TAC.EntityFrameworkCore/TAC.EntityFrameworkCore.csproj", "modules/TAC/src/TAC.EntityFrameworkCore/"]
COPY ["modules/TAC/src/TAC.Domain/TAC.Domain.csproj", "modules/TAC/src/TAC.Domain/"]
COPY ["modules/TAC/src/TAC.Domain.Shared/TAC.Domain.Shared.csproj", "modules/TAC/src/TAC.Domain.Shared/"]
COPY ["modules/Helper/src/Helper.EntityFrameworkCore/Helper.EntityFrameworkCore.csproj", "modules/Helper/src/Helper.EntityFrameworkCore/"]
COPY ["modules/Helper/src/Helper.Domain/Helper.Domain.csproj", "modules/Helper/src/Helper.Domain/"]
COPY ["modules/Helper/src/Helper.Domain.Shared/Helper.Domain.Shared.csproj", "modules/Helper/src/Helper.Domain.Shared/"]
COPY ["modules/ThumbprintVerification/src/ThumbprintVerification.EntityFrameworkCore/ThumbprintVerification.EntityFrameworkCore.csproj", "modules/ThumbprintVerification/src/ThumbprintVerification.EntityFrameworkCore/"]
COPY ["modules/ThumbprintVerification/src/ThumbprintVerification.Domain/ThumbprintVerification.Domain.csproj", "modules/ThumbprintVerification/src/ThumbprintVerification.Domain/"]
COPY ["modules/ThumbprintVerification/src/ThumbprintVerification.Domain.Shared/ThumbprintVerification.Domain.Shared.csproj", "modules/ThumbprintVerification/src/ThumbprintVerification.Domain.Shared/"]
COPY ["src/KMS.Domain/KMS.Domain.csproj", "src/KMS.Domain/"]
COPY ["src/KMS.Application.Contracts/KMS.Application.Contracts.csproj", "src/KMS.Application.Contracts/"]
COPY ["modules/IShariahRegistration/src/IShariahRegistration.Application.Contracts/IShariahRegistration.Application.Contracts.csproj", "modules/IShariahRegistration/src/IShariahRegistration.Application.Contracts/"]
COPY ["modules/IShariahRegistration/src/IShariahRegistration.Domain.Shared/IShariahRegistration.Domain.Shared.csproj", "modules/IShariahRegistration/src/IShariahRegistration.Domain.Shared/"]
COPY ["modules/Helper/src/Helper.Application.Contracts/Helper.Application.Contracts.csproj", "modules/Helper/src/Helper.Application.Contracts/"]
COPY ["modules/MemberProfile/src/MemberProfile.Application.Contracts/MemberProfile.Application.Contracts.csproj", "modules/MemberProfile/src/MemberProfile.Application.Contracts/"]
COPY ["modules/MemberProfile/src/MemberProfile.Domain.Shared/MemberProfile.Domain.Shared.csproj", "modules/MemberProfile/src/MemberProfile.Domain.Shared/"]
COPY ["modules/MemberAccount/src/MemberAccount.Application.Contracts/MemberAccount.Application.Contracts.csproj", "modules/MemberAccount/src/MemberAccount.Application.Contracts/"]
COPY ["modules/MemberDetailInquiry/src/MemberDetailInquiry.Application.Contracts/MemberDetailInquiry.Application.Contracts.csproj", "modules/MemberDetailInquiry/src/MemberDetailInquiry.Application.Contracts/"]
COPY ["Helper/Helper.csproj", "Helper/"]
COPY ["modules/MemberDetailInquiry/src/MemberDetailInquiry.Domain.Shared/MemberDetailInquiry.Domain.Shared.csproj", "modules/MemberDetailInquiry/src/MemberDetailInquiry.Domain.Shared/"]
COPY ["modules/MemberAccount/src/MemberAccount.Domain.Shared/MemberAccount.Domain.Shared.csproj", "modules/MemberAccount/src/MemberAccount.Domain.Shared/"]
COPY ["modules/IAkaunActivation/src/IAkaunActivation.Application.Contracts/IAkaunActivation.Application.Contracts.csproj", "modules/IAkaunActivation/src/IAkaunActivation.Application.Contracts/"]
COPY ["modules/IAkaunRegistration/src/IAkaunRegistration.Application.Contracts/IAkaunRegistration.Application.Contracts.csproj", "modules/IAkaunRegistration/src/IAkaunRegistration.Application.Contracts/"]
COPY ["modules/IAkaunRegistration/src/IAkaunRegistration.Domain.Shared/IAkaunRegistration.Domain.Shared.csproj", "modules/IAkaunRegistration/src/IAkaunRegistration.Domain.Shared/"]
COPY ["modules/ISaraanRegistration/src/ISaraanRegistration.Application.Contracts/ISaraanRegistration.Application.Contracts.csproj", "modules/ISaraanRegistration/src/ISaraanRegistration.Application.Contracts/"]
COPY ["modules/TAC/src/TAC.Application.Contracts/TAC.Application.Contracts.csproj", "modules/TAC/src/TAC.Application.Contracts/"]
COPY ["modules/ThumbprintVerification/src/ThumbprintVerification.Application.Contracts/ThumbprintVerification.Application.Contracts.csproj", "modules/ThumbprintVerification/src/ThumbprintVerification.Application.Contracts/"]
COPY ["src/KMS.Domain.Shared/KMS.Domain.Shared.csproj", "src/KMS.Domain.Shared/"]
COPY ["modules/Registration/src/Registration.Application.Contracts/Registration.Application.Contracts.csproj", "modules/Registration/src/Registration.Application.Contracts/"]
COPY ["modules/IShariahRegistration/src/IShariahRegistration.Domain/IShariahRegistration.Domain.csproj", "modules/IShariahRegistration/src/IShariahRegistration.Domain/"]
COPY ["modules/IAkaunRegistration/src/IAkaunRegistration.Domain/IAkaunRegistration.Domain.csproj", "modules/IAkaunRegistration/src/IAkaunRegistration.Domain/"]
COPY ["modules/MemberProfile/src/MemberProfile.Domain/MemberProfile.Domain.csproj", "modules/MemberProfile/src/MemberProfile.Domain/"]
COPY ["modules/MemberDetailInquiry/src/MemberDetailInquiry.Domain/MemberDetailInquiry.Domain.csproj", "modules/MemberDetailInquiry/src/MemberDetailInquiry.Domain/"]
COPY ["modules/MemberAccount/src/MemberAccount.Domain/MemberAccount.Domain.csproj", "modules/MemberAccount/src/MemberAccount.Domain/"]
COPY ["modules/MemberProfile/src/MemberProfile.EntityFrameworkCore/MemberProfile.EntityFrameworkCore.csproj", "modules/MemberProfile/src/MemberProfile.EntityFrameworkCore/"]
COPY ["modules/IAkaunRegistration/src/IAkaunRegistration.EntityFrameworkCore/IAkaunRegistration.EntityFrameworkCore.csproj", "modules/IAkaunRegistration/src/IAkaunRegistration.EntityFrameworkCore/"]
COPY ["modules/MemberAccount/src/MemberAccount.EntityFrameworkCore/MemberAccount.EntityFrameworkCore.csproj", "modules/MemberAccount/src/MemberAccount.EntityFrameworkCore/"]
COPY ["modules/IShariahRegistration/src/IShariahRegistration.EntityFrameworkCore/IShariahRegistration.EntityFrameworkCore.csproj", "modules/IShariahRegistration/src/IShariahRegistration.EntityFrameworkCore/"]
COPY ["modules/MemberDetailInquiry/src/MemberDetailInquiry.EntityFrameworkCore/MemberDetailInquiry.EntityFrameworkCore.csproj", "modules/MemberDetailInquiry/src/MemberDetailInquiry.EntityFrameworkCore/"]
COPY ["src/KMS.HttpApi/KMS.HttpApi.csproj", "src/KMS.HttpApi/"]
COPY ["modules/ThumbprintVerification/src/ThumbprintVerification.HttpApi/ThumbprintVerification.HttpApi.csproj", "modules/ThumbprintVerification/src/ThumbprintVerification.HttpApi/"]
COPY ["modules/ISaraanRegistration/src/ISaraanRegistration.HttpApi/ISaraanRegistration.HttpApi.csproj", "modules/ISaraanRegistration/src/ISaraanRegistration.HttpApi/"]
COPY ["modules/MemberDetailInquiry/src/MemberDetailInquiry.HttpApi/MemberDetailInquiry.HttpApi.csproj", "modules/MemberDetailInquiry/src/MemberDetailInquiry.HttpApi/"]
COPY ["modules/IAkaunActivation/src/IAkaunActivation.HttpApi/IAkaunActivation.HttpApi.csproj", "modules/IAkaunActivation/src/IAkaunActivation.HttpApi/"]
COPY ["modules/IAkaunRegistration/src/IAkaunRegistration.HttpApi/IAkaunRegistration.HttpApi.csproj", "modules/IAkaunRegistration/src/IAkaunRegistration.HttpApi/"]
COPY ["modules/Registration/src/Registration.HttpApi/Registration.HttpApi.csproj", "modules/Registration/src/Registration.HttpApi/"]
COPY ["modules/TAC/src/TAC.HttpApi/TAC.HttpApi.csproj", "modules/TAC/src/TAC.HttpApi/"]
COPY ["modules/Helper/src/Helper.HttpApi/Helper.HttpApi.csproj", "modules/Helper/src/Helper.HttpApi/"]
COPY ["modules/MemberProfile/src/MemberProfile.HttpApi/MemberProfile.HttpApi.csproj", "modules/MemberProfile/src/MemberProfile.HttpApi/"]
COPY ["modules/IShariahRegistration/src/IShariahRegistration.HttpApi/IShariahRegistration.HttpApi.csproj", "modules/IShariahRegistration/src/IShariahRegistration.HttpApi/"]
COPY ["modules/MemberAccount/src/MemberAccount.HttpApi/MemberAccount.HttpApi.csproj", "modules/MemberAccount/src/MemberAccount.HttpApi/"]
COPY ["src/KMS.Application/KMS.Application.csproj", "src/KMS.Application/"]
COPY ["modules/IAkaunRegistration/src/IAkaunRegistration.Application/IAkaunRegistration.Application.csproj", "modules/IAkaunRegistration/src/IAkaunRegistration.Application/"]
COPY ["Reporting/Reporting.csproj", "Reporting/"]
COPY ["modules/IAkaunActivation/src/IAkaunActivation.Application/IAkaunActivation.Application.csproj", "modules/IAkaunActivation/src/IAkaunActivation.Application/"]
COPY ["modules/ThumbprintVerification/src/ThumbprintVerification.Application/ThumbprintVerification.Application.csproj", "modules/ThumbprintVerification/src/ThumbprintVerification.Application/"]
COPY ["modules/TAC/src/TAC.Application/TAC.Application.csproj", "modules/TAC/src/TAC.Application/"]
COPY ["modules/MemberProfile/src/MemberProfile.Application/MemberProfile.Application.csproj", "modules/MemberProfile/src/MemberProfile.Application/"]
COPY ["modules/Helper/src/Helper.Application/Helper.Application.csproj", "modules/Helper/src/Helper.Application/"]
COPY ["modules/MemberDetailInquiry/src/MemberDetailInquiry.Application/MemberDetailInquiry.Application.csproj", "modules/MemberDetailInquiry/src/MemberDetailInquiry.Application/"]
COPY ["modules/ISaraanRegistration/src/ISaraanRegistration.Application/ISaraanRegistration.Application.csproj", "modules/ISaraanRegistration/src/ISaraanRegistration.Application/"]
COPY ["modules/MemberAccount/src/MemberAccount.Application/MemberAccount.Application.csproj", "modules/MemberAccount/src/MemberAccount.Application/"]
COPY ["modules/Registration/src/Registration.Application/Registration.Application.csproj", "modules/Registration/src/Registration.Application/"]
COPY ["modules/IShariahRegistration/src/IShariahRegistration.Application/IShariahRegistration.Application.csproj", "modules/IShariahRegistration/src/IShariahRegistration.Application/"]
RUN dotnet restore "src/KMS.HttpApi.Host/KMS.HttpApi.Host.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/src/KMS.HttpApi.Host"
RUN dotnet build "KMS.HttpApi.Host.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "KMS.HttpApi.Host.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "KMS.HttpApi.Host.dll"]
```

**Project Structure**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2G9VV.png)

Been at this for weeks and I appreciate any help! Thanks!

Comment: Try to find out what nuget package it's failing on. The error message you show is too generic and just says that something went wrong. There's probably a more specific error message earlier in the build log.

Comment: Hi @HansKilian, thanks for the reply! I'll look into the log and try to pinpoint the issue. But it seems to be multiple packages just from a glimpse. Does that mean, I'd have to go through all the failed packages and try to fix them one by one?

Comment: Probably you use private nuget feed, and just haven't provided credentials for it while building docker file. See `Nuget.config` for variables to be set.

Comment: If you want any of us to help you get it to work, you have to give us as much relevant information as possible. Right now, you haven't given us enough. We can only see that your restore fails, but not why. So all we can do is guess, like @Ryan does (no offence). Please update your post and add the error messages you see from nuget.